# specflow common steps shared across multiple features

Tags: c#, specflow

In a simple scenario - each feature file has its own step definitions class and the step definitions are not reused by other feature files, I see that BeforeScenario hook gets triggered properly.

When it comes to sharing common definitions, I read that I can inject the common definition class.

- feature 1 -  I have featureOneDefinitions class
- feature 2 - I have featureTwoDefinitions class
- Common Definitions - I have CommonDefinitions class
- I inject CommonDefinitions into both.

For testing purposes, all the steps in both feature files are in CommonDefinitions.

What I notice is that BeforeScenario in featureOneDefinitions and featureTwoDefintions are not triggered.

Even both feature files have some common steps, am I supposed to define all of them in both cs files and use scoped binding ?
For example, in featureOneDefinitions cs

```
[Scoped(featureOne)]
[@Given user "a" logs in]
public void Login() {
     commondefinitions.Login(xxx)
}
```

In featureTwoDefinitions cs

```
[Scoped(featureTwo)]
[@Given user "a" logs in]
public void Login() {
     commondefinitions.Login(xxx)
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `[Scoped(...)]` attribute above the login step, and don't replicate that step definition anywhere else?

Comment: Can you provide more code? You mention that the BeforeScenario hooks are not executing, but I don't see them in your code.

Comment: Do you have a `[Binding]` attribute above all of your step definition files?